# Google colab stops immediately after training yolov3-tiny

Tags: tensorflow, opencv, raspberry-pi, google-colaboratory, yolo

I'm currently trying to train tiny yolo weights.
I've already trained normal yolov3 weights but I want to make a live detector on a raspberry pi so I need the tiny ones.
The training of the normal ones went great no hiccups whatsoever, but the tiny weights just won't work.
I've tried like 4 different tutorials but the outcome is the same everytime.
Google colab just stops.
I also tried to train the normals again to test but also there it immediately stops.
-clear 1 after the command doesn't work and I've tried to modify the cfg in different ways but nothing. I don't know what to do anymore. Does anyone have an idea or a tip. That would be great.

Comment: Could you provide a minimum reproducible example? Its hard to tell what's going on just from what you wrote.

Comment: I use the command `!./darknet detector train data/obj.data cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg yolov3-tiny.conv.15 -dont_show -map -clear 1` In google colab and this is the outcome: `Done! Loaded 6 layers from weights-file 
Learning Rate: 0.001, Momentum: 0.9, Decay: 0.0005
 Detection layer: 16 - type = 28 
 Detection layer: 23 - type = 28 
Resizing, random_coef = 1.40 
 608 x 608 
 Create 6 permanent cpu-threads `